# Entry Point for LivePerson "Welcome Event" in Microsoft Bot framework using Direct Line

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework, liveperson

I'm currently integrating LivePerson via Direct Line using the Microsoft Bot Framework (v4).

In the LivePerson Developer [docs](https://developers.liveperson.com/third-party-bots-microsoft-direct-line-basic-content.html#the-welcome-event) it states:

> Ensure you have an ‘entry point’ in your bot that responds to the default ‘WELCOME’ action send by a new chat customer.

However, here are no code samples available on exactly how to do that. Does a new http endpoint needs to be built that LivePerson can call, or does this 'event' utilize the existing '/api/messages' endpoint?

The reason I want to react to this event is b/c when starting a chat with the bot directly in LivePerson test chat, I'm not seeing the bot's initial welcome message and first question. Nothing works until I type something, which the bot interprets as the answer to the first question you never see. When using the emulator and testing in WebChat in Azure, the bot works as expected.

I'm using Adaptive Dialogs, with a `RootDialog` as my entry point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is summed up in a blog post I wrote about this:
https://www.michaelgmccarthy.com/2021/03/13/sending-a-welcome-message-in-the-v4-bot-framework-via-direct-line-and-liveperson/

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that LivePerson sends a message to your message endpoint with the following payload:

```
{
  // ...
  "type": "message",
  "text": "",
  "channelData": {
    "action": {
      "name": "WELCOME"
    }
  }
}
```

In your onMessage event handler you should check for this WELCOME action and show your welcome message.

Comment: you're right. And that's outlined in the LivePerson docs here (https://developers.liveperson.com/third-party-bots-microsoft-direct-line-basic-content.html#the-welcome-event). My question was more geared to "how to I get a hold of that in the bot framework code"? I actually figured it out and I'm writing a blog post now. Once I'm finished, I'll return to this question and answer my own question.

Comment: Would be great to see a blogpost about a combined livechat botchat  scenario that actually works.